# Proof that $lim_{x->0,y->0}{\frac {\sqrt {a+x^2y^2} -1} {x^2+y^2}} (a>0)$ doesn't exist while a $\ne 1$.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0,y\to 0}{\frac {\sqrt {a+x^2y^2} -1} {x^2+y^2}} (a>0)$ doesn't exist while a $\ne 1$?

I already calculated that when a = 1 by multiplying $\sqrt {a+x^2y^2} + 1$ on both denominator and numerator and using the fact $x^2y^2<(x^2+y^2)^2/4$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function *can* have limit at $(0,0)$ for some $a_0$ then it can be defined at $a_0$ to be continuous at $a_0$. So suppose that we have some $a_0$ for which your function can be continuous at $a_0$.

If I recall corectly if $f$ is continuous then the limit is equal to iterated limits so we have $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}{\dfrac {\sqrt {a+x^2y^2} -1} {x^2+y^2}} =\lim_{x \to 0}(\lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac {\sqrt {a+x^2y^2} -1} {x^2+y^2})=\lim_{x \to 0}(\dfrac {\sqrt {a}-1}{x^2})$ and this limit can only exist if $\sqrt {a} =1$, that is, only if $a=1$.

Someone should correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Did you do all the theory behind this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Evaluating on the path $x=y$:
$$\lim_{x,y\to0}{\frac{\sqrt{a+x^2y^2}-1}{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\sqrt{a+x^4}-1}{2x^2}}=\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\sqrt a-1}{2x^2}}$$
If $a\ne1$ then $\sqrt a-1\ne0$ and a singularity exists at $x=y=0$, so the limit does not exist.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand why the $x^4$ can be dropped. What's the theorem behind this? Can you explain this for me?

Comment: @M.Chen Because $x^4=0$ when $x=0$.